# Templating system for managing what content is displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, templates

I am fairly new to PHP but have a project in mind and would like to force myself to learn as I go here. So I am using SB Admin 2 as a frontend template. I have a very basic login/logout working after having to completely scrap the old one I had to lieu of using prepared statements.

Im at the point where I am trying to decide how to hide/display content depending on the user role I specified. Does it make more sense to just create an admindashboard.php and userdashboard.php, or to hide the content in php (such as menu items in my sidebar) based on the user roll itself and have one dashboard.php. I saw someone mention a backend templating system and from my searching I see twig being pretty popular but cant find anything that really tells me this is the right track. Can someone point me to any documentation that might help with this? Thanks

Comment: Since you said you're fairly new to PHP I recommend you to just use the basics, (to learn the advance stuff later), and don't use twig. Twig is great, but it would be overcomplicating to use this for a beginning user.

You could just do something like this: 
if($userType == "admin") { require_once("admindashboard.php"); } else { require_once("user dashboard.php"); }

once you learn the basics of PHP, you could go to CodeIgniter (a simple MVC framework)

Comment: thank for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

I have a very basic login/logout working after having to completely scrap the old one I had to lieu of using prepared statements.

> Answer: You have to simply put role column in your user table.

Im at the point where I am trying to decide how to hide/display content depending on the user role I specified.

> Answer: use session management like for administrator use code like
> this `<?php if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])!='' && $_SESSION['role']=='Admin'): ?>`
>
> and write html code for your navbar here in between ending `<?php endif; ?>`

for the rest use your other navbar code for non-admins hope you understand on navbar and for the page security.
`

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])==''){
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php';</script>";   }
    if($_SESSION['role']!='Admin'){
     echo "<script>window.location='home.php';</script>";
    }elseif($_SESSION['role']=='Employee'){
    }else{ $_SESSION['role'];}
    ?>  

`
```

this is simplest role access control.
If you need to understand role based access control ask a question i will try to answer it to.

Comment: thanks. Would you recommend loading a seperate php file then for users + admins? so adminprojects.php and userprojects.php? Is this a better approach then something like this ? id ideally like to stick with the same single file instead of having two seperate ones for each user level i have.
<?php 
check user role, if admin 
load these divs
if user
load these divs
?>

Comment: @unknownid I would like to recommend loading separate files for both users and separate one for admins because in this approach you can handle the flow of your application without complications.

Comment: Yes sure! you can load it.